# How to change Figure 1: to bold Fig.1. in latex

Tags: floats, formatting, captions

I am using default setting in `LaTeX` that show

```
Figure 1: Caption....
```

Now, I am following the format of Magnetic Resonance Imaging journal that require

**Fig. 1.** Caption

I tried to add the below line in the top, but it did not look like my expected

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
...
\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Fig1.png}
 \caption{MRI format.}
 \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

Could you help me to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Using `caption` package this is quite straightforward:

```
 \captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},name={Fig.},labelsep=period}
```

In this case, no `\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}` is needed

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},labelformat={default},labelsep=period,name={Fig.}}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering

  \includegraphics[scale=1]{beeduck}
 \caption{MRI format.}
 \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank Christian Huper. I run it, it change to **Fig.1: **. It still has ":", instead of .

Comment: @user3051460: Just updated, in my first version I forgot the colon

Comment: @user3051460: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Comment: OK, this produces labels such as  Fig.1 below the images.  But what about the references.  \cref{fig1:fig3}  Produce Figure 1c.  How can I get Fig.1c or something like that.

Comment: @skan: That's another question, isn't it? This question was about the label format of caption, but not about cross-referencing format

Comment: But they are a pair, if you change the label of the figure you also want to change accordingly its reference.

Comment: @skan: Not necessarily.

Comment: @skan: See section 7.3. of the `cleveref` manual about the usage of abbreviations.

Comment: For **tables**, use: `\captionsetup[table]{labelfont={bf},labelformat={default},labelsep=period,name={Tab.}}
`