# Change name for numbered figures

Tags: floats, captions, lyx

Is there any way to change the numbered figure caption in Lyx?
For example, in Section 2 to be 2.1.1 then 2.1.2, etc. but I don't want to write in the caption "Figure 2.1.1. blabla" I want "Fig. 2.1.1 blabla"

Comment: See if this can solve your problem - https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85776/28557 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/276795/28557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the answers to questions:  [Change figure numbering for appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85776/28557) and [How to change Figure 1: to bold Fig.1. in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276795/how-to-change-figure-1-to-bold-fig-1-in-latex):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\captionsetup[figure]{name={Fig.}}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\begin{document}
\section{First}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}
  \caption{Example figure.}
 \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```